# behavior not expected but working, I need some explanation please

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, fetch, crud

I am on the CRUD step with hooks and everything is working but I don't understand why the `Axios.post` doesn't need `.then` in this case.

If I send only `customer` instead `customer[0]` nothing happens, then the `.then(response => console.log(response))` returns nothing. I guess that the `customer[0]` has already the right format: `[{}]`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Form, Container, Col, Row, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

// import data
import fields from './customerFields'; // <= array of object

function AddCustomers() {
 
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState([{}]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setCustomer([inputValue]);
  }, [inputValue]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newCustomer = [...customer, inputValue];
    setCustomer(newCustomer);

    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/clients';
    
    Axios.post(url, customer[0])
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = event.target;
    const { name } = event.target;
    const newValue = { ...inputValue, [name]: value };
    setInputValue(newValue);
  };

  // return
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col className="col-form-label-sm">
          <h3 id="">Identité du client</h3>
          <Form
            action=""
            className="form-group"
            onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}
          >
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>{fields[0].label}</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name={fields[0].name}
                type="text"
                value={inputValue.name}
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>{fields[1].label}</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name={fields[1].name}
                type="text"
                value={inputValue.name}
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>{fields[2].label}</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name={fields[2].name}
                type="text"
                value={inputValue.name}
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button type="submit" variant="warning">
              Ajouter un client
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default AddCustomers;
```

Comment: You don't need `.then` if you don't plan to do anything with the response. I think you're sending the wrong customer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an asynchronous operation (`Axios.post(url, customer[0])`) and not waiting for it to resolve, so you're just leaving the promise [floating there](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md). If you don't care if the operation succeed or failed that is fine, but in most cases you want to either handle the error received or do something with the result.

About why `Axios.post` is accepting `customer[0]` that's because it accepts anything in the second parameter it can send in a POST request. You're always setting your customer as an array with the `inputValue` variable inside (`setCustomer([inputValue]);`) so `inputValue` is what you send as `customer[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

ohhh! I got it, I think this version is better :

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/clients';
    Axios.post(url, customer);
  };
```

thank you @jonrsharpe